# When is my sqlite Data Base created?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have this piece of code, that helps me to manage the db, but I do not know when a data base is created

```
package es.aadesigners.pruebabd;

/**
* Created by Andrea on 29/2/16.
*/

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String nombre,    SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {

    super(context, nombre, factory, version);

  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //aquí creamos la tabla de usuario (dni, nombre, ciudad, numero)
    db.execSQL("create table usuario(dni integer primary key, nombre text, ciudad text, numero integer)");

  }
}
```

I also have a doubt on the Super sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super creates a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database. **The database is not actually created or opened until one of getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() is called.**

Source:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper